# Can't Access localhost or 127.0.0.1 in wamp

Tags: mysql, apache, localhost, wamp

I was using wamp 2.1a for my wordpress blog and a website. It was working fine. Then I caught a google redirect virus. I tried hard to get rid of it, finally i fixed it. Then, suddenly my wamp server stopped working, I mean both the services were running but when I opened localhost or 127.0.0.1, it just kept loading, and went on forever till I closed the browser's tab. Then I upgraded to wamp 2.2a and the problem is still there.

I've also checked the hosts file, tried to change the port to 8080 for apache, but it didn't help. I do not have skype (and never used it) so there's no port 80 conflict. When I restart the services, the apache service starts but the mysql service doesn't. When I click wamp tray menu, click on the remove service for mysql, a message box appears saying - mysqld.exe has stopped working. The only option I have there is close program.

I can't access my blog so I can't so any testing. Please tell me if this happened to you or if you have a solution to this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check/test your apache config and review the logs, I suppose you have fixed it so much, that the apache is not starting :)
If you find a error message paste it here so then we could help you.

Comment: Yeah, as @Rolice says: THE LOGS! Look at them

Comment: i'm a begginer. Not got what you guys are saying. Hope you reply!

Comment: I've seen people with similar symptoms and I believe it has to do with the previous install having left something behind that is conflicting.  Visit http://forum.wampserver.com/search.php and I'm sure you'll find 1000 things to check before you find the problem. Pretty sure it's an upgrade issue.  BTW, can you access it via LAN? 192.168.x.x?  Let us know whether Apache is running or all services are down. Make/access a plain `.html` file to see if it loads locally/remotely.

Comment: @Rolice sounds more like a mysql problem.

Comment: @Milo LaMar, it could be a lot of things and possible that you are right, but apache is dependent on this failure (and we need to track the problem), that's why nothing is loading. :D
OK, when you click on the wamp menu, what you see? What is the status of apache, mysql and other services.. they should be painted in some color. If you want you can share any changes you have made...

Comment: when i click it, i see that mysql isnt working, but apache is working. I try click on restart all services, only apache restarts, mysql doesn't. The wamp icon stays yellow because mysql doesn't start. I manually start only mysql by click the wamp icon>mysql>service>start/resume service , but it doesn't start. Wampserver is online and there's no issue of wamp not going online. And please tell me what i have to do with the logs and how.

Comment: I think the problem is because I've got a google redirect virus, which, after trying so many times, is not fixed.

Comment: Then find the mysql logs and tell us the errors inside. Possibly something is deleted, but mysql does not know and fails (database or other).

Comment: It wasnt b'coz of google redirect virus, i removed the virus but the problem is still there. I had to reinstall wamp b'coz the spyware remover removed mysqld and httpd. Now the wamp icon is green but can't access localhost or 127.0.0.1 . I tried making a file in www directory but the loading circle just goes on, and page just keeps on loading. And please tell me how do u check the mysql logs. And Thanks that you guys are helping!

Comment: I also tried xampp previously and the problem was there, so i uninstalled it and reinstalled wamp.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try different web browser? I guess it is browser problem, clear your browser cache, might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following solution in another post here (from Sergiu Butnarasu) which worked for me.

Modify the apache HTTPD.CONF file. Change "Listen 80" to "Listen 0.0.0.0:80 http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,93143